# Not enough heap memory to run weka 3.8.4

Tags: java, weka, heap-memory

i am using weka 3.8.4  and i have 4gig allocated by default,that's 1/4 of my system ram memory as my heap memory, i opened the RunWeka config settigs as decribed in earlier solution  but it does not allow me save when edited and it does not contain maxheap, only maxstack
For clarity purpose i have numbered the line in the pic, please how do i resolve this... what line do i edit and how do i save it.

[image 1 RunWeka config file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlbg4.png)

[image 2 shows the error thrown by weka](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Fzfg.png)

[Image 3 shows the location of weka config file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39j1i.png)

Comment: Line 16 shows a `#javaOpts#`, so set `javaOpts` to `-Xmx8g` in the same place where you define `maxstack`.

Comment: i tried the recommendation and increase to 8 and got the same error and incresed  to 12 and got the same error, is there something else i should be doing?